# How to capture original endpoint URI within an expression (Recipient List EIP)

Tags: apache-camel

I'm attempting to use the Recipient List EIP to dynamically generate the consumer endpoint URI during runtime based on configuration entries in a database (http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).  I've got a number of routes that I want to handle this way so I'd like to build something that can handle multiple routes generically.

Therefore, my idea is to keep an in memory map of these URI values keyed on some type of identifying information (original endpoint URI seems like a logical choice) which would be updated if/when the database is updated to keep the routes in sync, and prevent having to go to the database for every exchange.  Using the RouteBuilder, I am setting up the route with the recipient list and Bean expression.

```
from(endpointUri).recipientList(bean(MyBean.class, "getUri"));
```

I know that I can capture various objects such as the exchange, body, headers (as long as I know the name), etc using the Bean binding for the getUri method.  Is it possible to somehow get the original endpoint URI value so that I can use it as a key to fetch the correct consumer endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exchange interface has [getFromEndpoint()](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#getFromEndpoint%28%29) method which returns an Endpoint. The Endpoint interface has [getEndpointUri()](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Endpoint.html#getEndpointUri%28%29) method which returns a String. Perhaps that's what you need? If that's not sufficient, you could set header value(s) at some point and then subsequently retrieve them later in your route.

Comment: Note that getEndpointUri() may return a URI in an altered form compared to how the route was defined.  e.i I defined a route with this name (as the producer), "direct:route1", and getEndpointUri() returned "direct://route1".